# Points inside CanvasJS Graph are existing but invisible

Tags: angular, websocket, canvasjs

I am building a web-application which is supposed to show sensor data. it recieves the sensordata via a websocket. A component subscribes to the websocket, on `notify()` the observer pushes the correct  values into an Array which is afterwards (supposed to be) rendered onto the graph. But when the `render()` function is called, there are no points showing up inside the graph.

When I insert a point/points into the `dataPoints[]` array before the component recieves any data, the point does show up. For example if i insert array of random points into the array in the `ngOnInit()` funciton.

But as soon as data arrives via websocket all the otherpoints dissapear and the recieved points are invisible. I know they are there, because if you hover over them, their coordinates are shown, but they are as white as the background

The following shows the callback function where i insert the values into the dataPoints array (which is declared at beginning of file)

```
//this is where the component subscribes to the websocket and 
wsSubscription = this.wsService.getObservableWebsocket().subscribe(
      data => {

        this.messageAsObject = JSON.parse(data);
        this.dataPoints.push({x: this.messageAsObject.Content[6],y: this.messageAsObject.Content[8]});
        // correct values are pushed into the dataPoints array 

        this.chart.render();
        //it does render but points are invisible
      },
      err => console.log(err),
      () => console.log("observable stream is over")
     );


  ngOnInit() {          
//example values would be inserted here

  this.chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2", 
  {
    theme : "light1",
    zoomEnabled: true,
    zoomType: "xy",
        animationEnabled: true,
        exportEnabled: true,
        title: {
            text: "XZ Distance"
        },
        subtitles:[{
            text: ""
        }],
        data: [
        {
            type: "line",                
            dataPoints: this.dataPoints
    }],
    axisX:{
      title:"X Value",
      minimum: -50,
      maximum: 50,
      gridColor:"black",
      gridThickness: 1    ,
      crosshair : {
        enabled: true,
      },
    },
    axisY:{
      title:"Z Value",
      minimum: -50,
      maximum: 50,
      gridColor:"black",
      gridThickness: 1    ,
      crosshair : {
        enabled: true,
      }
      }

    });

  this.chart.render();
}
```

what did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing particularly wrong with the code it self. The problem were the points i tried to insert. The values were between 0.00000005m upto 300m, but CanvasJS is only able to show points over 0.2m